# Neon lamp connected in parallel to a motor

Tags: dc-motor, high-voltage, neon

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpKfxL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I see a high voltage (100Vdc-1000Vdc) output when I measure with a voltmeter when the motor just starts to run. I connected a neon lamp in parallel to the motor and when I started the circuit, I saw that the lamp did not light up (I was waiting for the lamp to light up).

I also tried with a coil instead of a motor, but the result was negative.

Why didn't the lamp light up?

From the neon lamps in the control pen.

Comment: Neon lamps usually don't work at 12V. But please describe in more detail what kind of neon lamp you have, maybe it is rated for 12V?

Comment: What do you call a "high voltage"? Neons require about 80V to light.

Comment: As soon as the engine starts, the voltage rises (if you don't put a diode) and exceeds 80V, right? @SimonB

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope? If so, use it using single sweep or normal mode trigger. Voltmeters are not designed to monitor dynamic events. If you are getting a high voltage glitch due to wiring inductance, the pulse width may be so low that you can't see the bulb light up. Try observing the neon bulb in total darkness with dark adapted eyes.

Comment: _"I see a **high** voltage..."_ - define 'high'.

Comment: I can't see anything in that circuit that could produce more than 12V, except possibly a brief spike at the moment the switch is turned off.

Comment: What kind of voltmeter? If it's an auto-ranging digital multimeter and no voltage is present it will switch to its lowest range. Is it possible that the meter briefly shows an invalid reading when the switch is closed, before it has switched to the correct range for the 12 V input, and you're mistaking this for a 100V or 1000V spike?